# Issue of display in css

Tags: css

I have following CSS and I want all my three select box in one line.Though I have implemented display as inline but its not working in div..

```
.block_feedback .field select { color: #FFF; width:375px; height:20px; line-height:17px; margin-left:13px; margin-top:4px; display:none; background-color:#00A2B1; border:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; }

 <div class="field" >
            <select name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth" class="w_def_text" style="width:150px;">
              <?php getmonth(); ?>
            </select>
            <select name="dobdate" id="dobdate" class="w_def_text" style="width:80px;">
              <?php getbirthdate(); ?>
            </select>
            <select name="dobyear" id="dobyear" class="w_def_text" style="width:80px;">
              <?php getyear(); ?>
            </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which browsers are you seeing this behavior on?  I see all 3 selects inline in firefox (via jsfiddle)

Comment: same: http://jsfiddle.net/YXNAH/

Comment: My question is not about select are not visible. I wish to have all three select in same line (horizontally in same line)... not vertically same line(one after another.)

Comment: @RahulSingh, which browser?  The selects are aligned horizontally for me...

Comment: @RahulSingh Are you saying you want it to look like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YXNAH/1/

Comment: @jackwink I want same as eg. by joseph but it is showing me as u showed me in ur eg. HOw Can I align all horizontally.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` to the `select` in your css, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/YXNAH/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left` to the select's as motoxer4533 said,
and in ".field" add `float:left;` and a specific width

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `select` is an inline element, you don't need to float them. When rendered visually, inline elements do not usually begin on a new line.

http://jsfiddle.net/qByj4/

Also I would avoid the inline CSS. You can use its id to set a width.